# Workaround for insufficient permissions during webapi serialization

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I have a webapi which is outputting a result like so:

```
[
  {
    "Households": 3,
    "Municipality": "WC001",
    "Tenure status": "Owned and fully paid off",
    "Income category": "R 2 457 601 or more",
    "Computer": "No"
},
...
```

The first two items (Households & Municipality) are always present, the subsequent items - there may be any number of them (minimum one).

I can generate this by using a `List<dynamic>` object on the server. However, when I upload to the shared hosting environment, I get the error:
`The 'ObjectContent' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.` with innerException `"Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.ReflectionPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed."`

I can't change the trustlevel in web.config to full, because the host company has locked that down.

I thought this is because a dynamic object needs reflection to check the property names (other webapi calls returning POCOs work fine).

So I tried changing it from a `List<dynamic>` object to a `List<Dictionary<string, string>>` - but I still get the same error.

Is there a workaround to creating this 'dynamic' object without needing reflection to serialize it?

Comment: Do the other API calls serialize your POCOs to Json as well?

Comment: Yes, they do - works absolutely fine. So I suppose they're also using reflection, but there's something different here where the property name is dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

This is a potential solution I've just found: build the result at a Json string and change the method to an `HttpResponseMessage`, then return the string directly avoiding the JSON.NET serializer, like so:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
...
var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
response.Content = new StringContent(sb.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
return response;
```

I'd prefer to use objects/classes than the StringBuilder, but this at least works.